# Remove Row Data If Qty Zero

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I have a data like this in Table Receipts, for the plus value is the amount of receipt of goods while the negative value in case of returns.

[image: Table Receipts]

In the picture above, the Receiver_No 01267A is the receipt of the first item with Qty_Received 1. Then there is the return of goods on the receipt number of goods 01268A. I want this transaction not to show up.

Here's statement where i have tried.

```
 select I2.Receiver_No, 
        I2.Purchase_order, 
        I2.PO_Line, 
        I2.Qty_received
   from (Select Purchase_order, 
                PO_Line 
           from Receipts 
       group by Purchase_order, 
                PO_Line 
         having sum(qty_received) <>'0') I1 inner join 
        Receipts I2 On 
             I1.Purchase_Order = I2.Purchase_Order and 
             I1.PO_Line = I2.PO_Line
```

But the result did not meet with i want.
Please Help.

Comment: Using a whole lot of guessing, it seems that you are interested in retrieving all rows from the table, which are not cancelled out by another row? So, `-1` is cancelled out by `1` and `0.5` is not cancelled out by anything, therefore show the row containing `0.5`?

Comment: seems you want the actual balance of the rows  and remove all the others  .. explain better

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you update your question so that it shows the question you are trying to ask?

Comment: @DeniYunus how can you say the return transaction is connected to the actual transaction? What if you have (2, 4, -1, -1, 5)? Maybe you just need the sum() for each purchase_order/po_line group

Comment: From a logical point of view, your question is still confusing. You have a purchase order with one item (whatever that may be). That item has a purchase receipt (with a quantity of 1), as well as a return receipt (with a quantity of 1), and then another purchase receipt for the same purchase order (with a quantity of 0.5). Are you selling the same item more than once?

Comment: Even if you don't have partial returns, what if you have (2, 2, -2)? Should you delete the first or the second row?

Comment: @peter, yes i'm.

Comment: @alex it will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the very limited data that you have provided. If you care to provide more information about what the data looks like, then it will be easier to come up with a better solution.

*If you have data with a lot of lines that have identical quantities, then this solution will not work.*

```
SELECT
    r.Receiver_No, r.Purchase_order, r.PO_Line, r.Qty_received
FROM
    receipts r
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        purchase_order 
    FROM 
        receipts s 
    WHERE 
        r.qty_received = -s.qty_received
    )
```

Comment: ya, i have a lot line and this answer is not what i want.

Comment: @DeniYunus Ok, fair enough. If you can update your question, I will be happy to help. Before updating, read this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

If your requirement is to fetch rows with quantities less than one and not the negative ones :

```
SELECT * FROM Receipts  WHERE  ABS(QtyRecvd) >0 AND ABS(QtyRecvd) < 1
```

Comment: This answer does seem a bit contrived, even if the original question is rather unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
   SELECT * FROM Receipts where Qty_received>0 AND Qty_received < 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I want. As already explained in the comment, for the plus value is the amount of receipt of goods while the negative value in case of returns.
I want this return transaction not shown.